# Find minimum number of columns in matrix necessary to ensure all rows are unique

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix

Say I have an m x n matrix consisting purely of dummy variables i.e. all values in the matrix are either 0 or 1.

```
[0 1 ... 1 1
 1 1 ... 1 0
 0 1 ... 0 0
 | |  \  | |
 0 0 ... 1 1
 1 1 ... 0 0
 0 0 ... 0 0]
```

What is the most efficient method of finding the fewest possible columns of the matrix necessary to ensure all rows are unique?

All rows in the initial matrix are unique. The dimensions of the matrix are not square, and the matrix is of a size as to make a brute force solution intractable. Say 500 x 1000

Comment: Not quite clear, but it seems likely to be NP-hard. You are trying to find the lowest dimensional subspace (of a certain type) on which a set of distinct vectors projects to a set of distinct vectors.

Comment: I have a feeling that this will prove isomorphic to the Set Coverage problem.  You might look up that for inspiration.

Comment: @Prune That seems like a pretty good hunch. It is definitely that sort of problem.

Comment: Do you know anything about number of rows vs number of columns?

Comment: Do you need an exact solution? If you can accept a greedy algorithm, treat each row as a binary integer, bitwise-and them with *2^n - i* for `i in range(n)` - O(n), check for duplicates - O(m), if you find none you can discard the `i` th col from the end. You'll get a greedy solution in O(m x n), but won't necessarily get the best solution because you're only doing one pass through the columns. You might get some improvement by discarding any column that is all 1 or 0 upfront, O(m), and you know your solution has a lower bound of log(m) so can stop early if you hit it

Comment: Yes, I don't think an exact solution is feasible. I'll try implementing the greedy algorithm as soon as possible

Comment: @Dan: I don't follow -- a number ANDed with 2^(n-i) (I presume you meant "n-i" to have parens) can only give one of two possible results, so if you have more than 3 rows, you're guaranteed to have a duplicate.

Comment: @j_random_hacker yes I was mistaken. I meant to make a series like `[1110, 1101, 1011, 0111]`, so if n is 4, 2^4 is 10000 so as a starting point I actually meant 2^n - 1 to get 1111. And instead of subtracting `i`, you need to subtract `2 ** i` in `range(n)`. So it comes down to `for col in range(n): col_remover = (2 ** n) - 1 - (2 ** col); for binary_num in rows_as_binary_nums: binary_num & col_remover ....`. I guess it might be simpler to ignore the binary stuff, and just zero out a row manually in the same loop that you check for dupes (using a hash table to keep it O(n)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be formulated as a set cover problem, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36452133/4039466. Your sets are the columns, and the space you're covering is the set of pairs of rows. This is probably doable for 1000 linear variables and 250,000 constraints.