# Determining columns which produce unique row for primary set keys

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm

I am looking to find a way of getting columns names from dataframes which combination produce unique rows.

Let's say I have a `df` which looks like this:

```
id      name        location    cost        supplier            code
1       A           Paris       10          Google              100
1       B           London      10          Facebook            100
2       A           Rome        20          Google              100
2       B           Paris       20          Google              105
1       C           London      10          Facebook            200
```

Then I would expect to get `id, name` because having these columns I can identify every row. I have checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49998457/how-to-find-a-columns-set-for-a-primary-key-candidate-in-csv-file) but it simply returns combinations of all columns. Since that question was asked 3 years ago, I am wondering if pandas have a method of automatically checking which columns produce unique rows.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36449631/finding-minimal-subset-of-columns-that-make-rows-in-a-matrix-unique) may be helpful if you are after an efficient implementation. I am not aware of any method that does this automatically.

Comment: the previous answer looks correct given semantics.  Your dataset `id, name` would be a valid primary key.  Without brushing off my final year dissertation from 30 years ago I can't remember the relational theory algorithms that can be used to find minimal 3NF keys from inspection ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Out of interest I looked into this.  There are multiple valid primary key combinations for this data set.  *semantic* a primary key is defined as a combination of attribute that uniquely identifies a row

I have used `set_index()` instead of `drop_duplicates()` to test the semantic.

Clearly you could add to semantic, such as minimum number of columns or maximum number of columns.

#### Updated

Have coded change to semantic, cost of testing is significant.  Have flexibility to optimise by defining minimum and maximum number of columns to be considered in candidate primary key.

```
import io
import itertools
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""id      name        location    cost        supplier            code
1       A           Paris       10          Google              100
1       B           London      10          Facebook            100
2       A           Rome        20          Google              100
2       B           Paris       20          Google              105
1       C           London      10          Facebook            200"""),sep="\s+",)

MINCOLS = len(df.columns) // 3
MAXCOLS = len(df.columns) - 1

valid = []
for combi in itertools.chain.from_iterable(
    itertools.combinations(df.columns, r)
    for r in range(max(MINCOLS, 1), min(MAXCOLS, len(df.columns)))
):
    try:
        df.set_index(list(combi), verify_integrity=True)
        valid.append(list(combi))
    except ValueError:
        pass
valid
```

#### output

```
[['id', 'name'],
 ['name', 'location'],
 ['name', 'cost'],
 ['location', 'code'],
 ['id', 'name', 'location'],
 ['id', 'name', 'cost'],
 ['id', 'name', 'supplier'],
 ['id', 'name', 'code'],
 ['id', 'location', 'code'],
 ['id', 'supplier', 'code'],
 ['name', 'location', 'cost'],
 ['name', 'location', 'supplier'],
 ['name', 'location', 'code'],
 ['name', 'cost', 'supplier'],
 ['name', 'cost', 'code'],
 ['location', 'cost', 'code'],
 ['location', 'supplier', 'code'],
 ['cost', 'supplier', 'code'],
 ['id', 'name', 'location', 'cost'],
 ['id', 'name', 'location', 'supplier'],
 ['id', 'name', 'location', 'code'],
 ['id', 'name', 'cost', 'supplier'],
 ['id', 'name', 'cost', 'code'],
 ['id', 'name', 'supplier', 'code'],
 ['id', 'location', 'cost', 'code'],
 ['id', 'location', 'supplier', 'code'],
 ['id', 'cost', 'supplier', 'code'],
 ['name', 'location', 'cost', 'supplier'],
 ['name', 'location', 'cost', 'code'],
 ['name', 'location', 'supplier', 'code'],
 ['name', 'cost', 'supplier', 'code'],
 ['location', 'cost', 'supplier', 'code']]
```

Comment: Great answer, this wil run more efficiently. Maybe you can add `keys = min(valid, key=len)` to get the minimal amount of columns.

Comment: I've added `sorted(valid, key = len)[:10]` just to check the first 10.

Comment: all of the `valid` combinations have been tested,  invalid ones will have not have been added to any list

Comment: If I follow, it seems that if a subset `S` of columns is semantic, then any subset of columns containing `S` is also semantic. On the other hand, if a subset of columns `S` is not semantic, neither is any subset of `S`. Maybe one can avoid the `verify_integrity` check for some subsets.

Comment: the concept/semantic is the definition of a primary key - it uniquely identifies all rows.  Basic relational data theory defined by Codd in 1970.   The code is generating candidate keys and testing against this semantic (the combination is a primary key for all rows in the dataframe).  if you remove `verify_intergrity` parameter you are no longer testing that a candidate key is a primary key

Comment: @RobRaymond I had something as follows in mind: assuming that `[id, name]` is a semantic key, there is no need to test if `[id, name, location]` is a semantic key.

Comment: `[id, name]` is a candidate key in relational data terminology, which needs to be tested if it is indeed a possible primary key

Comment: I think I am not communicating clearly. I mean to suggest an algorithm that keeps track of semantic keys as your traverse column subsets. Assuming a set `S` is known to be semantic, one can deduce that any set `combi` containing `S` is also semantic, so calling `df.set_index(list(combi), verify_integrity=True)` is redundant.

Comment: ok correct,  given it's testing shorter candidate keys to longer candidate keys.  If a shorter key turned out to be a primary key, a longer candidate key that contains a validated primary key it will also be a primary key without needing to use expensive test

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that stops at the first valid minimum combination of keys:

```
def find_minimal_index(df):
    from itertools import combinations
    for n in range(1, len(df.columns)+1):
        for c in combinations(df.columns, n):
            if not df[list(c)].duplicated().any():
                return df[list(c)].columns

find_minimal_index(df)
```